# Listview, single choice in touch screen?

Tags: android

Goal: have a LIstView show a list of text strings. The user can select an item by touching it. The selected item is visibly different to those not selected.

In short I want to have a simple scrolling list box that works using trackballs AND touch mode.

There are many posts asking for this, but none seem to get an adequate answer. This is such a simple requirement, why is there no article on this?

I looked at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html but that won't work in touch mode: the orange background is displayed, something unachievable in touch mode without extreme geek wizadry, for something that is quite frankly what all newbies expect out of the box.

I suspect that the only way to achive a touch mode selectable listbox (ListView in google speak), is to stick radio buttons in there. All of a sudden my little text list view is beccoming a monster.

Can anyone explain the simplest way to do a single choice ListView that displays the item selected so the user can figure out that it is selected, in touch mode? After fumbling for days, I really am not fussed if it has radio buttons, singing cockatoos, or whatever, so long as it's simple to code.

Comment: So the list items should be still clickable or only selectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the example that Google provides:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List10.html

It uses radio buttons

Comment: Thanks that does the trick. To get the radio buttons to appear, the ArrayAdapter needed android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. Documentation on this is non existent (did a search on google's developer site for simple_list_item_single_choice not much came up). Also noticed, that to get the selected item, you need to call getCheckedItemPosition(), as getSelectedItem() returns null in touch mode.

Answer (score 0):

Wat do u want to do? Just highlighting the row in the `ListView` which is selected.rt? for this u can use this.

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/highlighter"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

Write this code in your XML file